# Insert radio button selected value into database

Tags: c#, sql

I am building a C# Windows application with 2 radio buttons for gender. I'm using a simple insert query to insert data in the database.

Can anyone help me with inserting the selected radio button value to the database? I am using 2 radio buttons, not a radio button list.

For the moment my query is as follows:

```
Class1.ABC("insert into emp(code,names,m_name,desgnation,gender) 
                        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox2.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox3.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox4.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox5.Text + "','" + 
                                     radioButton1.Checked+"' )");
```

Comment: How exactly is it failing?  As an aside, the code you're showing is a prime candidate for a SQL injection vulnerability. You don't want to have "Tommy Tables" as a user.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Srima you are specifying five columns,but you are passing six values.Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Selman22 - I think you've nailed it, at least with the example as presented.

Comment: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) !!

Answer (score 0):

You can check `checked` property and set value as per your requirement.

```
Class1.ABC("insert into emp(code,names,m_name,desgnation,gender) 
                        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "',
                                '" + textBox2.Text + "',
                                '" + textBox3.Text + "',
                                '" + textBox4.Text + "',
                                '" + textBox5.Text + "',
                                '"+ radioButton1.Checked ? "Male" : "Female" +"' )");
```

Note : Use `parameterized queries`

Comment: I have 2 radio buttons. then how can I write this? thanks for your cooperation

Comment: add radio buttons in one panel or group box. When their are more than one radio button in one container at time only one is selected. So if `radioButton1` is selected another is not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Inser RadioButton Text

Like this

```
Class1.ABC("insert into emp(code,names,m_name,desgnation,gender) 
                        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox2.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox3.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox4.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox5.Text + "','" + 
                                     radioButton1.Text + "' )");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string RadioButtonText()
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        return  radioButton1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        return  radioButton2.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method, pass a list of `RadioButton`s to the method and perform validation and eventually retrieve the `Text` property inside this method. This allows you to extend the functionality in the future easier when needed, keeps your original code clean (no strange inline validation/checks).

I'd do something like:

```
public string GetSelectedRadioButtonText(RadioButton[] radioButtons)
{
    // possible additional checks: check multiple selected, check if at least one is selected and generate more descriptive exception.

    // works for above cases, but throws a generic InvalidOperationException if it fails
    return radioButtons.Single(r => r.Checked).Text;
}

public void YourMethod()
{
    Class1.ABC("insert into emp(code,names,m_name,desgnation,gender) 
                values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + 
                             textBox2.Text + "','" +
                             textBox3.Text + "','" +
                             textBox4.Text + "','" +
                             textBox5.Text + "','" +
                             this.GetSelectedRadioButtonText(new[] { rb1, rb2 }) + "' )");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Try this:

Add a Label, make it invisible.get the checked radiobutton's value into the label. Now in sql statement, use label's value(which is in fact the checked radiobutton's value) to insert into 'gender'. 
I recommend this only if you are a beginner & anyhow want to get the program running.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Ofcourse. Instead of getting the value from the checked radiobutton, you get the value from a label or textbox whose value is actually the value of the checked radiobutton.

Comment: You need to identify the difference between an answer and a comment !!! Have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @huMpty duMpty, ^taken into consideration now. thanks